# How do I just show online people in Gmail Hangout (formerly Talk/chat)?

Tags: gmail, google-hangouts

The new Google Hangouts in Gmail option seems interesting, and while it shows my most recent contacts, most of them aren't online (some never are because of the Google account they use).  Can I sort them by their online state, as the old chat does?

Comment: I sure hope they're working on that. It's hard enough to see the thin-green bar underneath the online users' profile pics.

Comment: looks like they don't have that option...lot of ppl have asked this and nobody knows how to.

Comment: There are a lot of features missing from Gmail Hangouts right now.  Show online only is one, "Off the record" is another, deactivate smiley auto-replacements is another, and so on.  The best answer is going to be a non-answer: Wait, or switch back to Talk/Chat until Hangouts is feature complete enough for you.

Comment: You are really looking at switching back to the original Google Chat Interface, so switch back - http://daxserver.com/revert-back-to-google-chat-from-hangouts-in-gmail/   This just shows you to click the 'Revert to old chat' button at the bottom :)

Answer (score 5):

No. A Google employee I know told me the following: "the idea is to free you from worrying if the person you are talking to is on mobile, on a tablet, in front of a computer, etc, and instead give you one channel by which to communicate."

For those of us who **like** to know exactly which friends are on mobile (or even online at all) this is a big step backward, but it is the direction Google wants us to go.

Your best bet is to run a multi-IM client like Pidgin or EBuddy, which has more flexible display options, and switch to Hangouts when your friends are ready to video chat.

Answer (score 0):

At this time, it is possible to see who is online in Hangouts. From [See people’s online status - Hangouts Help](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3111918?hl=en)

> When you want to start a Hangout with someone on your computer, you
>   can look at the person's profile picture in your Hangouts list to see
>   whether they're online and available or not. If they're not online
>   right now and they have the last seen feature turned on, you can see
>   when they were last on Hangouts.
>
> Search for and add contacts to your Hangouts list. You can also manage
>   your contacts list to pin specific people to the top of the list or
>   hide others.