# How to see who is online with the new "Hangouts" in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-hangouts

I just upgraded to from regular Google chat to the new Hangouts feature [using this article](http://www.omgchrome.com/how-to-enable-hangouts-in-gmail/), but one thing I can't figure out is how to see if people are online. In the regular Google chat there was a green ball next to the people that are online but now it just shows picture and name and I don't see any "online" indicator.

Am I missing something?

Comment: This would appear to be a duplicate of [How do I just show online people in Gmail Hangout (formerly Talk/chat)?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/44846) , but unfortunately there's no answer there yet, either.

Answer (score 1):

Update 12/05/2014:

> Starting today you’ll see some changes in your conversation list in Hangouts, including message snippets and the return of green “availability” bubbles to make it easier to see which of your friends are currently active.

[Source](https://plus.google.com/+Gmail/posts/BcSckCPuxr9).

> Green presence indicators, like a line under a person’s profile picture in the Hangouts list or a green chat icon on mobile, mean that a person is signed in and available to chat. If there isn’t a line under their profile picture or their chat icon is gray, the person might be idle, have Snooze Notifications enabled, or not be available to chat.

[Source](https://support.google.com/a/answer/4213661). (Under *Presence indicators*.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Pidgin?
http://www.pidgin.im/

Using this plugin?
Google Invisibility Tracker

Description
This plugin informs you when a buddy of yours goes invisible. This is possible only if your buddy uses Gmail chat or Google Talk Lab Edition or iGoogle chat.
http://www.siorarina.net/google-invisibility-tracker/

Untested, just passing along the opportunity to try.

Answer (score 0):

A thick solid green line of around 5px at the bottom of the user's profile picture with a 2 to 3 px distance indicates that the user is online.

If not, then there will be no such line there.

This suits for both Google Plus Hangout in web browser and Google Chrome's Hangout extension.